# mappedBy is not working for me in Spring Data JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

when I try to relate two entities (Person, CellPhone) mappedBy that I have read in the little that I have been in spring data JPA that is used to indicate bidirectional relationship, and that is used by the owner entity to indicate that there is an instance of it on the other side (disclaimer: this is for now the little I have understood)

the entities are the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Integer id;
   private String firstname;
   private String lastname;
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<CellPhone> cells;
   //getters and setters
   public void addCell(CellPhone cell) {
    if (this.cells == null){
        cells = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    this.cells.add(cell);        
   }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "cellphone")
public class CellPhone {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String brand;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Person person;
}
```

this is the code that I run for test purposes:

```
    Person per = new Person();
    per.setFirstName("arnulfo");
    per.setLastName("gutierrez");
    CellPhone cell1 = new CellPhone();
    cell1.setBrand("sasomo");
    CellPhone cell2 = new CellPhone();
    cell2.setBrand("ni me asomo");
    per.addCell(cell1);
    per.addCell(cell2);
    repo.save(per);
```

I am shown this in console

```
   Hibernate: insert into person (firstname, lastname) values (?, ?)
   Hibernate: insert into cellphone (brand, person_id) values (?, ?)
   Hibernate: insert into cellphone (brand, person_id) values (?, ?)
```

but when y run a select of CellPhone the output is the following:

```
   mysql> select * from cellphone;
   +----+-------------+-----------+
   | id | brand       | person_id |
   +----+-------------+-----------+
   |  1 | sasomo      |      NULL |
   |  2 | ni me asomo |      NULL |
   +----+-------------+-----------+
```

can someone tell me why this occurs please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate tries to keep your in-memory state with the DB, but that's hard for graphs that have cycles. So hibernate ignores the **inverse side** (the class which has the `mappedBy` attribute).

If you set `Cellphone.person`, hibernate will store the values correctly. This is explained in more detail in the [Hibernate user guide: Bidirectional @OneToMany](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional).

To handle bidirectional associactions correctly, it's recommended to have one method (on either side) that know how to set the properties on both sides of the association so the data in-memory is correct. To do this, the code for `addCell` shoud be something like:

```
   public void addCell(CellPhone cell) {
    if (this.cells == null){
        cells = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    this.cells.add(cell);        
    cell.setPerson(this); // add this line.
   }
```

And the collection `Person.cell` should never escape the class Person, otherwise you can get something outside the class changing the collection.